# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf Neko HTML Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to run an example with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I get that error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Cannot perform conversion to XML from legacy HTML: The
>   nekoHTML library is not in classpath. nekoHTML 1.9.15 or newer is
>   required for processing templates in "LEGACYHTML5" mode

These are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is my application properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
```

When I add Neko HTML dependency error goes away. However it should be included via my current dependencies. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Maven, simple add this dependency:

**mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml**

*results nothing*

It seems spring-boot-thymeleaf does not include **nekohtml** libraries.

---

For gradle, you could find the version you want in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml, and find the gradle include script like this:

```
compile group: 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml', name: 'nekohtml', version: '1.9.22'
```

Comment: You're right. Spring Boot does manage the nekohtml dependency (so you can add that dependency without the version), but the thymeleaf starter does not bring it by default.

Comment: Surprising for me :) Seems that Neko HTML is a must for Thymeleaf but it didn't included at spring-boot-thymeleaf. I thought I miss something. Thanks!

Comment: If, for example, you use the HTML5 mode, the Neko library is not needed at all. Much better as an optional dependency to be included only when a project needs it.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer does not completely answer the question of OP. Besides telling "add this" you should explain why you add it and if it solves the question at hand.